# Django - setting staff member as default for new users

Tags: python, django, django-admin

everybody!

I'm trying setting as default staff_member to new users, but I cannot find any solution. I really need help. My codes are below.

models

```
class Participante(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    email = models.EmailField()
    dt_criacao = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        ('staff status'),
        default=True,
        help_text=('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

forms

```
class ParticipanteForm(UserCreationForm):

    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Primeiro nome')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Último nome')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

views

```
def cadastro(request):
    form = ParticipanteForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ParticipanteForm(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            #User(request, username=username, password=password1)
            form.save()
            return redirect('dashboard')

    return render(request, 'cadastro.html', locals())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that your `UserCreationForm` is pointing to the `User` model and not your custom `Participante` model. Thus, users are not being saved in the table which you expect them to be.

In `settings.py`, set the `Participante` model to be your user model (your `Participante` model will also have to inherit `AbstractUser` to keep the `User` model's methods, etc.

Read: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser

```py
# settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app.models.Participante'
```

```
# your_app.models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class Participante(AbstractUser):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    email = models.EmailField()
    dt_criacao = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        ('staff status'),
        default=True,
        help_text=('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

Then in your form, point to your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` using `get_user_model()`

````py
# forms.py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class ParticipanteForm(UserCreationForm):

    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Primeiro nome')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Último nome')
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']```
````

Answer (score 1):

You set the `.is_staff` attribute of the `.instance` wrapped in the `form`, so:

```
def cadastro(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ParticipanteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.is_staff = True
            form.save()
            return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        form = ParticipanteForm()
    return render(request, 'cadastro.html', locals())
```

Your `ParticipanteForm` also works with the `User` model, not the `Participante` model. If you set the `Participante` as the *user model*, you can work with the [**`get_user_model()`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model):

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class ParticipanteForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Primeiro nome')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Último nome')
    
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

It will however require some extra work to make `Participante` the user model. Django has a topic on [*substituting a custom user model* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Comment: His form has the `User` model within the `Meta` subclass. Is that not the problem? His users are being saved to the `User` model and not the `Participante` model.

Comment: @Nicky: exsactly what is the user model you use? The current model can not be used as user model since it should satisfy a number of contracts.

Comment: @Nicky: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: I'm not the person who asked the question. His `is_staff` has the default True, but I assume that his users are being saved to the `User` model and not his custom `Participante` model. Otherwise, `is_staff` would always be true.

Comment: Won't his form have to then point to the model at`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` even if his custom model is set as it? Pointing to `User` does not point to his custom model.

Comment: @Nicky: it should use `get_user_model()`, since `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` is just a string, and that would not work. But before that, it will require some extra work to get this working.

Comment: Sure `get_user_model()` is what they should be using (given that they have set their `AUTH_USER_MODEL`. I think that is the issue here.

Comment: Actually, Participante is a model but is not related to the User. 
This system is to register people who participated in the events, their name are Participante. (sorry for my english mistakes)

Comment: So, I wanna add as staff member User, not Participante

Comment: @BeatrizGomes So why add the `Participante` model to the question if it's of no use?

Well in that case, just do `form.instance.is_staff = True` or override your form's `.save()` method to always apply True to `is_staff`.

Comment: My mistake, @Nicky. I'm sorry for that. It works! Thank you.

Comment: @Nicky, two questions, I hope you don't mind. How can I change the permissions in the view? Do you have one reference that can help me? I'm learning to read the docs yet.